# Searching Java ArrayList and returning element location - indexOf() not working.

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been writing a program that asks a user to input a name, ticket type and fine.  The user input is being stored into a text file.  I am reading the text file into an array named 'list' and prompting the user to search for a 'keyword'.  I am storing the keyword as a String = keyword.  When I use a println(list.indexOf(keyword)), I am getting a "-1" output even though the keyword being searched for is returning found!  That is where I am stuck...I'm not sure why the indexOf() method cannot find the element but my search for the keyword is able to.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Note: My end goal is to search for the "keyword", find the elements location and return true.  I will then be asking the user for a new name, ticket type and fine.  I will replace the information in the text file and write the new information to the text file mentioned earlier.  Thanks in advance for the input.  Code is included (I'm new to Java so please be nice :0) I will clean the code up once I finish the program.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.Collator;
public class Project {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String name = "";
String ticketType = "";
double fine = 0;
char quit;
boolean cont = true;

while (cont){
do {
    //Create file Project.txt
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Project.txt", true));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Prompt user to enter name, ticket type, fine or 'q' if done
    System.out.println("Name:");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ticket Type:");
    ticketType = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("fine:");
    fine = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("press 'q' if you are done entering or 'c' to continue entering");
    quit = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    //Write user input to Project.txt file
        out.print(name + ", ");
        out.print(ticketType + ", ");
        out.printf("%.2f",fine);
        out.println();
        out.close();
}
while (!(quit == 'q'));{
    System.out.println("done");
}
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("are you sure youre done");
System.out.println("enter y to if your done, n to enter more");
char Continue = input.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
//Prompt user in the are done entering
//If 'y', program moves on.  If 'n' loop back to beginning
if (Continue == ('y')){
    cont = false;
    }
//Done entering names to list
//Now read in file to array and sort alphabetically

}
 Scanner readArray = new Scanner(new File("Project.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (readArray.hasNext()){
         list.add(readArray.nextLine().toLowerCase());
    }
    readArray.close();
    Collections.sort(list, Collator.getInstance()); //sort array alphabetically
    //print array as list comma separated
    for (String value : list){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    //Prompt user to enter a name they want to search for   
    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("search keyword: ");
    String keyword = search.next().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("searching for: " + keyword);
    //Search array 'list' for user input
    boolean found = false;
    for (String value : list) {
      if (value.contains(keyword)) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      System.out.println("found");
      System.out.println(list.indexOf(keyword));

    }
    else {
      System.out.println(" not found");
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: You aren't checking if your List contains the keyword. You are checking if any String in your list contains the keyword. So if your List has a String `"Something Test"` and you would search for `"Something"` as a keyword `indexOf("Something")` would return -1, but your search would find something as you would check `"Something Test".contains("Something")` which returns true.

Comment: in addition, there is no need for a separate loop to find if the list contains the requested value. you can invoke indexOf() and if the returned value is -1, then you know the search failed

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I am searching for "Something Test".contains("Something") and i am getting the correct return.  The string I am searching for does return found.  What I am struggling with is returning the element location in the array.  I want to return the element and then use set(int index, element).  I just need to know how to get the elements location because indexOf() is not working (returning -1 for location)

Comment: Hint: you expect us to spend our time to help you. So **you** please take the 5 minutes it takes to properly format/indet your input to us. And beyond that: read about [mcve]; you put up a lot of code; and I have the feeling that only parts of that would really be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the index of the element that you found via you're search you can just get that index at the same point were you currently set your boolean found to true:

```
Integer foundIndex = null;
for (String value : list) {
    if (value.contains(keyword)) {
        foundIndex = list.indexOf(value);
        break; // we stop iteration because we got our result
    }
}

boolean found = (foundIndex!=null);
if (found) {
   //....
} else {
  //....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but, I am still not getting the elements location.  I added the above code to my program and i have added System.out.println("found") and System.out.println(foundIndex).  If i run the program and enter name: mike, ticket type: speed and fine: 25, i search for mike (keyword), In my output I get found but, it is returning -1 for foundIndex value.

Comment: Integer foundElement = null;
     for (String value : list) {
       if (value.contains(keyword)) {
         foundElement = list.indexOf(keyword);
         break;
       }
     }
     boolean found = (foundElement != null); 
     if (found){
       System.out.println("found");
       System.out.println(foundElement);
     
     }
     else {
       System.out.println(" not found");
     }
     
   }
 
 }

Comment: @M.Luke change `list.indexOf(keyword);` to `list.indexOf(value);`

Comment: Works exactly as I need it to!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly your issue then the code below will help you

```
list.add("for example")
list.add("for")
list.add("example")
System.out.println(list.indexOf("for example"))
System.out.println(list.indexOf("for"))
System.out.println(list.indexOf("example"))
```

indexOf does not search for a keyword in the element. It search for the index of element which is equal to the passed argument.